# How to increase Upsert performance in my SQL code

Tags: c#, sql

I have a job which runs every night and gets data from source A and puts it in destination A. We are talking about approximately 120000 records.

I am using this approach in my code

```
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    var sql = "BEGIN TRANSACTION; UPDATE ExpandedGroupInformation SET " +
          "Description = @Description, " +
          "IndexInFind = @IndexInFind, " +
          "SchoolCode = @SchoolCode, " +
          "SchoolName = @SchoolName, " +
          "WhenChanged = @WhenChanged, " +
          "WhenCreated = @WhenCreated, " +
          "Deleted = 0, " +
          "CanExpanded = @CanExpanded, " +
          "StudentCount = 0, TeacherCount = 0, ParentCount = 0 " +
          "WHERE Name = @Name ";

sql += " IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BEGIN ";

sql += "INSERT INTO ExpandedGroupInformation (ObjectGuid, Description, IndexInFind, Name, " +
                "SchoolCode,SchoolName,  WhenChanged, WhenCreated, Deleted, CanExpanded, StudentCount, TeacherCount, ParentCount, Type ) " +
                "values (@ObjectGuid, @Description, @IndexInFind, @Name, " +
                "@SchoolCode, @SchoolName, @WhenChanged, @WhenCreated, 0, @CanExpanded,0,0,0,0) ";

sql += "END COMMIT TRANSACTION; ";

connection.Execute(sql, group);
```

}

This code runs for each row from source inside a loop

Is there a better way of doing it which improves time?

Comment: Remove the loop and process the *set* of rows

Comment: but then how do I pass the value to the sql?

Comment: Open connection and begin/commit transaction perform outside the loop

Comment: Most SQL dialects support [`MERGE`](https://blog.jonschneider.com/2016/08/bulk-upsert-into-sql-server.html) which lets you update all of your existing keys and insert new ones within one query. It would be helpful to mark your question with the specific RDBMS you use.

Comment: You need to completely ABANDON the "RBAR" mindset.  RBAR = "row by agonizing row".   There are several ways to pass down "sets" of data.  You should tag this question with your (SINGLE) RDBMS.  That may be a necessary clue to help.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?